# HTML - Number Input Limit (Go Up/Go Down 10 to 10)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, digit

I want when i press up arrow number change (increase) 0-to-10 /then/ 10-to-20 / 20-to-30
I mean 10 to 10. and if you press down arrow, number change (decrease) 10 to 10.

```
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="99999999" />
```

I don't know JavaScript or jQuery well. couldn't found anything about this in google/stackoverflow. Obviously i haven't any code on JSFiddle.

Comment: When you set the input type in the HTML, jquery no longer gets implemented so try searching HTML documentation instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`step` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-step). This specifies how far to increase or decrease the number. For example:

```
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="99999999" step="10" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `step` attribute for this

```
<input type="number" value="0" step="10" min="0" max="99999999" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/132/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...by using `step`

```
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="99999999" step="10"/>
```